# Can mulitple pipenv environments share the same directory for libraries?

Tags: python, pipenv

I have a directory structure like this:

```
.
├── script 1
│   ├── Pipfile
│   └── Pipfile.lock
├── script 2
│   ├── Pipfile
│   └── Pipfile.lock
├── script 3
│   ├── Pipfile
│   └── Pipfile.lock
├── script 4
│   ├── Pipfile
│   └── Pipfile.lock
├── script 5
│   ├── Pipfile
│   └── Pipfile.lock
├── script 6
│   ├── Pipfile
│   └── Pipfile.lock
└── ...etc
```

And many of the scripts specify the same packages - for example all the scripts use `matplotlib` (38MB) and `pandas` (60MB). If I have 20 scripts, that equates to almost 2GB of space of repeated libraries. Since these scripts are all made available via a Docker image, that is quite a lot of space.

Is it possible to use `pipenv sync --system` such that all python packages are stored in the same folder?

This would still require that imports in every script folder resolve to the correct versions as specified in the `Pipfile.lock` directory (all scripts use the same Python version)

(I'm quite new to Python, and if there is a better approach, or if I have missed something obvious, please let me know!)

I'm finding that if I do:

```sh
cd script 1
pipenv sync --system

cd ../script 2
pipenv sync --system

etc
```

that the dependencies defined in the `script 2` lockfile replace dependencies defined in the `script 1` lockfile. For example, in Script 1 would have installed `"version": "==1.22.3"`, but pipenv installs `"version": "==1.16.6"` based on the second script.

As such, when running script one I get the error:

```
ImportError: Matplotlib requires numpy>=1.17; you have 1.16.6
```

(I'm not actually sure if the dependencies installed by prior `pipenv syncs` are replaced or if the import just isn't finding the correct version)

Comment: It would be a bad idea for local installation, but should be ok in docker: you can install system-level packages (with `pip install ...` without any environment) and reuse it with `pipenv --site-packages`. See [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/419).